# Script to display workbook title in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I read on here how to use the script `=sheetName()` to display the sheet name, but is there another script I can use to display the workbook title?

I use daily sheets and the title for the sheets are the date.  When I print them, I want it to display the date (located in the title).
(I know I can show the title in the print settings but that's a lot of steps if I'm mass printing)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getName()) method from the Class Spreadsheet.

---

We don't need a script to display the Spreadsheet title when printing.

1. Click on File > Print
2. On the right panel, expand the Headers & footers section
3. Check the Workbook title to add it to the default field or click on Edit Custom Fields to add it to the field that prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already said that I knew that option.  I'm trying to find a way that it auto inserts the title in a cell so I don't have to go in the print options for each and every sheet.

Comment: @Justin: You edited your question to said that 5 minutes ago :)

Comment: Yes, I was just making it more clear for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into the script editor, then save and close the script editor:

```
function GetSheetName() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
}
```

Then do `=GetSheetName()` in a cell and you will have the workbook title.

If you want the title of a sheet/tab within the workbook, use this instead:

```
function GetSheetName() {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```